# url restriction in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter. I am creating a shopping cart website. I have a product detail page where the url is 'localhost://shopcart/product/productid'. I copy this url and then logout from the site. Then I paste that url in the url it goes to that page. How could I restrict that?

Comment: If you don't login, can you access the page?

Comment: provide the controller for that.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor for the controller, check if the user is logged in. If not logged in, store the URL in session, redirect to login page, and then redirect back after log in.

You will need to provide code if you're looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

make a two header template first is header_outside.php second is header_inside.php
use header_outside.php for the module that does not uses or does not needs any login details , 
and use header_inside.php for the module that user needs to login to use that module

here is the solution make a function that will check the session of the user if he/or she is login and call the function inside header_inside.php

e.g :

```
<? if(!$this->session->user('session variable for login'))redirect('module that uses header_outside','location')?>
<html>
//your code
```

thats the way how to limit the user to access your module that needs login.